# Unable to access collectionView cell variables using global variable

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

Here i made a collectionView cell variable for accessing both objects. But unable to access the objects inside the cell variable

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    var cell: UICollectionViewCell!
    if collectionView == collectionView1 {
        cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellAttachment", for: indexPath) as! AttachmentCell
        cell.imgAttachment.image = imageArray1[indexPath.row]
        cell.delegate = self
    }
    else if collectionView == collectionView2 {
       cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellAttachmentView", for: indexPath) as! AttachmentViewCell
       cell.imgFileIcon.image = imgArray2[indexPath.row].fileIcon
    }
    return cell
```

> Value of type 'UICollectionViewCell?' has no member 'imgAttachment'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies here.

```
var cell: UICollectionViewCell!
```

You have declared the cell to be of type `UICollectionViewCell`. So, no matter which subclass you store inside it, you cell will only be of type `UICollectionViewCell`.

You should change it like this,

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    if collectionView === collectionView1 {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellAttachment", for: indexPath) as! AttachmentCell
        cell.imgAttachment.image = imageArray1[indexPath.row]
        cell.delegate = self
        return cell
    } else if collectionView === collectionView2 {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellAttachmentView", for: indexPath) as! AttachmentViewCell
        cell.imgFileIcon.image = imgArray2[indexPath.row].fileIcon
        return cell
    } else {
        // Return the proper cell for other cases
    }
}
```

Or, if you are adamant you need only a single return statement at the end of the delegate, then you could do it like this,

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    var yourCell: UICollectionViewCell!
    if collectionView === collectionView1 {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellAttachment", for: indexPath) as! AttachmentCell
        cell.imgAttachment.image = imageArray1[indexPath.row]
        cell.delegate = self
        yourCell = cell
    } else if collectionView === collectionView2 {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellAttachmentView", for: indexPath) as! AttachmentViewCell
        cell.imgFileIcon.image = imgArray2[indexPath.row].fileIcon
        yourCell = cell
    } else {
        // Return the proper cell for other cases
    }
    return yourCell
}
```

Comment: but don't forget, first example doesn't return any cell

Comment: @RobertDresler noted. Corrected! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need to silent the compiler by casting the `cell` as `AttachmentCell`. See the below example,

```
(cell as! AttachmentCell).imgAttachment.image = imageArray1[indexPath.row]
(cell as! AttachmentCell).delegate = self
```

The reason compiler is not able to recognize the variable is the declaration of variable `cell` as `UICollectionViewCell`. As there is no `imgAttachment` variable in `UICollectionViewCell` so compiler will complain.

Comment: Then what is the requirement of casting before

Comment: That is redundant actually. See @Rakesha answer where you can define the cell directly as an `AttachmentCell` so you don't really need to do any casting.